# C# Overriding interface method from another interface

Tags: c#, interface

Let's say I have interface

```
public interface IRepository
{
    string GetValue();
}
```

And then I need to extend this interface so it supports cache

```
public interface ICachedRepository: IRepository
{
    void SetCache(string value);

    string GetValue(bool ignoreCache = false);
}
```

As you can see, I want to override `GetValue` method so that it has `ignoreCache` argument. But it looks like I overload method, instead of overriding it. Is there any way to fully override `GetValue`, so that class that implements `ICachedRepository` won't need to implement `GetValue` from `IRepository` ?

Comment: You can override any method of base type if it is marked as **virtual**. read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual), it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the signature when you want to override a method, therefore `GetValue(bool)` creates an overload, not an override (that the method has a default argument doesn't make a difference). *But* your `ICachedRepository` *does* implement `GetValue()` as you inherit the base interface.

When you write an implementation for your interface, you have to specify both methods:

```cs
public class RepositoryImplementation : ICachedRepository
{
    public string GetValue() { GetValue(false) }
    public string GetValue(bool ignoreCache) { ... }
    public void SetCache(string value) {...}
}
```

The `GetValue()` method is part of `ICachedRepository`, even though you don't declare an override in it in `ICachedRepository`. It's actually illegal to declare overrides in interfaces.

Side note: I would remove the default parameter specification from `GetValue(bool ignoreCache = false)` because it's confusing when another overload without the parameter exists. Instead, make sure that calling `GetValue()` and `GetValue(false)` perform the same operation.

Comment: It would make sense the parameterless`GetValue()` to call the specific `GetValue(false)` and not the other way around as shown above.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Of course, yes, fixed. What I wrote was an infinite recursion, anyway...

Comment: It's a pity that you can't provide a default implementation of `IRepository.GetValue()` in `ICachedRepository`. But you *could* define a default `string GetValue(bool ignoreCache) => GetValue()`.